# JavaFX native packager custom post-image scripts

Tags: javafx

Making a JavaFX app that does remote EJB, and it turns out I need the java executable in the bundle. Building for Mac, Windows, deb, and rpm.

Three questions:

1) Is there a way to get the java executable to end up in the bundle without using the post-image scripts?

2) If not, *are* there post-image scripts for Linux?  (deb & rpm both)  These don't show up in the verbose notes like they do for Mac and Windows.

3) Still having a problem with my mac script today. I've verified that the java executable is copied to the right place in the dmg-image tree, but doesn't end up in the final.  Yesterday they worked, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I did to make it work or again to make it stop working today.

Yes, I'm using verbose and have tried all sorts of bash tricks to expose inner workings.

More detail here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_cookbook_using_drop

Thanks for any help,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

True, there is no post-image script for linux (that I could find).

However, you can modify the rpm spec file to do what you want by adding a custom script to the %install section.

For example, a default spec file %install section might look like this:

```
%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/opt
cp -r %{_sourcedir}/YOURAPPNAME %{buildroot}/opt
```

To add the java executable to the build, just add these 2 lines:

```
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/opt/YOURAPPNAME/runtime/jre/bin
cp -p ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java %{buildroot}/opt/YOURAPPNAME/runtime/jre/bin/java
```